# Enabling basic authentication on ASP NET Core - 404

Tags: asp.net-core, basic-authentication

I am using this middleware as the concepts are new to me

https://github.com/blowdart/idunno.Authentication/tree/master/src/idunno.Authentication.Basic

I've implemented startup exactly as it says

However, every time I post to the WeatherForecast end point I get a 404 if the [Authorize] identifier is there. I did some reading and hence added the AuthenticationSchemes but same result

It cannot be a missing redirect, which is the other problem, as the controller is just returning content in that page?

Please can someone point me in the right direction?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddAuthentication(BasicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddBasic(options =>
        {
            //options.Realm = "idunno";

            options.Events = new BasicAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnValidateCredentials = context =>
                {
                    if (context.Username == context.Password)
                    {
                        var claims = new[]
                        {
                            new Claim(
                                ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,
                                context.Username,
                                ClaimValueTypes.String,
                                context.Options.ClaimsIssuer),
                            new Claim(
                                ClaimTypes.Name,
                                context.Username,
                                ClaimValueTypes.String,
                                context.Options.ClaimsIssuer)
                        };

                        context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(
                            new ClaimsIdentity(claims, context.Scheme.Name));
                        context.Success();
                    }

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
    }
```

Then this

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Controller looks like this:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = idunno.Authentication.Basic.BasicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionController<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Content("Authorised"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running this in `Development` mode?

Comment: Yes - what should it be?

Comment: What happens if you put the `UseAuthentication` and `UseAuthorization` pair in the correct place? i.e. in between `UseRouting` and `UseEndpoints`?

Comment: Thank you very much, it now works!

Answer (score 1):

As per comment, some of the commands were in the wrong order